# Selenium WebDriver takes a lot of time to find element in iframe

Tags: java, iframe, selenium

I am using Webdriver 2.39.0 and FF 26 (I also tried with 27) and I am having the following html:

```
<div id="sCaroiaj_harta">
<iframe id="ifr_layout_prepay" 
scrolling="no" 
frameborder="0" 
src="http://test-harta.ci.rmn.ro//layout/prepay/init/1/lat/45.738235215834/lon/21.222698590278/of_lat/0/of_lon/0/adresa/073074072061064061/iZoom/15/caroiaj">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="map_container_2">
<div id="map_container_1">
<div id="map_container" class="clearfix">
<div id="map" class="olMap cursorMap cursorMapFix"></div>
</div>
</div></div></body></html>
</iframe>
</div>
```

I also have the following code which should the element with id "map" inside the iframe:

```
Browser.waitElement(By.id("ifr_layout_prepay"));
driver.switchTo().frame("ifr_layout_prepay");
Browser.waitElement(By.id("map"));

public class Browser {    
public static void waitElement(By locator) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
}}
```

What happens is that the test finds the iframe, switches to the iframe, than it takes about 5 minutes before it finds the 'map' element and continues with the other instructions. I want to specify that when trying to find 'map' it just hangs more than 10 seconds, the time for waiting I have put in.

So I have no idea why this happens, does anyone experienced this before or has any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Did you check that the frame is fully loaded ? I've got similar problem due to an image whichi didn't exist. 
Firefox was waiting for the page to be loaded. Chrome didn't wait. could you test with chrome ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using WebDriverWait just try with your own wait method.

```
public static void waitForAnElementToAppear(By by) {
            int i=0;
            while(!isElementPresent(by))
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                if(++i>100)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
   }
```

You can find **isElementPresent** method implementation [here](http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2012/07/iselementpresent.html).

Now try your flow something like below.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("ifr_layout_prepay");
MyWait.waitForAnElementToAppear(By.id("map"));
click(By.id("map"));
```